# How can I add a character before a specific word, considering that I change another character in the middle of that word using .replace in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I have a code which replaces special characters with other characters, but I need to add another character before that word. For example,

I have a word: `"zài"` and I change it to: `"zai"`, but I need: `"azai"`

So an "a" should be placed before that word. Thank you.

```
var charac = function(txta, txti) {
  var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 

  var txta = str.replace(/ā/gi, "a").replace(/ē/gi, "e");
  var txti = str.replace(/á/gi,"a").replace(/é/gi, "e");

  var cum = str.replace(str, txta).replace(str, txti);

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = cum;
};
```

Comment: Just use string concatenation. You can do it using the operator `+`.

Comment: @Oriol: I don't think that will work, since the idea is to add a character only if that word is getting replaced, presumably because the language has different rules for words with and without diacritics.

Comment: @Oriol: I tried concatenation, it gives "a" character in the beginning of the sentence but not before the word I change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var str= 'hello zāi hi ē sure á ikr é'
var words = str.split(' ');
words.map(function(word){
 if(word.match(/[āáēé]/g)) return 'a' + word;
 return word;
}).join(' ').replace(/[āáēé]/g, function(letter){
  switch(letter){
    case 'ā':
    case 'á':
        return 'a';
    break;
    case 'ē':
    case 'é':
        return 'e';
    break;
  }
})
```

Comment: More help on replace function:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: My only guess is that I should add some RegEx to specify the location where I need to place a character, but somehow nothing works, I tried [$'a(āáēé)], I'm not sure though it the right RegEx.

Comment: From " dào hé jǐ " to " idao ehe uji ", from " zhèng fǔ guó jiā " to " izheng ufu iguo ajia ".

Comment: @ArsenyMikhalev The top code works you just have to add all the types of letters of accents into the switch statement and the regex

Comment: GREAT! Thank you very much, @Edwin, it works perfectly! I just didn't get it right the first time, sorry.

Comment: You're very welcome @ArsenyMikhalev. and if you want can you please mark the answer as correct. Check mark under the voting. Thanks

Comment: I'm new here, sorry i didn't check it right away, thank you again!

Comment: I have a problem with output, the code given by @Edwin works great in console, but for some reason it doesn't work when I try to get it into HTML page by
  
var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = words;

Any suggestion, please?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Edwin I have this code:

```js
document.getElementById('replaceBtn').addEventListener('click', function(evt){
    var demo = document.getElementById('demo');
    demo.innerHTML = demo.innerHTML.split(' ').map(function(word){
        if(word.match(/[āáǎà]/g)) {
            return 'a' + word.replace(/[āáǎà]/g, 'a');
        } else if(word.match(/[ēéěè]/g)) {
            return 'e' + word.replace(/[ēéěè]/g, 'e');
        } else if(word.match(/[īíǐì]/g)) {
            return 'i' + word.replace(/[īíǐì]/g, 'i');
        } else if(word.match(/[ōóǒò]/g)) {
            return 'o' + word.replace(/[ōóǒò]/g, 'o');
        } else if(word.match(/[ūúǔù]/g)) {
            return 'u' + word.replace(/[ūúǔù]/g, 'u');
        } else if(word.match(/[ǖǘǚǜ]/g)) {
            return 'u' + word.replace(/[ǖǘǚǜ]/g, 'ü');
        } else {
         return word;
        }
    }).join(' ');
})
```

```html
<p id="demo">tā yě jiù rén</p>
<button id="replaceBtn">Click</button>
```